# Automatically generated property {get; set;} vs {get; private or protected set;} in C#

Tags: c#, properties

I see a lot of code uses automatically generated property like `{get; private set;}` or `{get; protected set;}`.

What's the advantage of this `private` or `protected` set?

I tried this code, but it's the same when I have `Foo{get; set;}`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Foo {get; private set;}
    public static void RunSnippet()
    {
        var x = new MyClass();
        x.Foo = 30;
        Console.WriteLine(x.Foo);
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It makes a property read-only by external sources (i.e. classes that aren't `MyClass` and/or its subclasses). Or if you declared the property `protected` with a `private set`, it's read-only by its subclasses but writable by itself.

It doesn't make a difference in your class because your setter is private to that class, so your class can still access it. However if you tried to instantiate `MyClass` from another class, you wouldn't be able to modify the `Foo` property's value if it had a private or protected setter.

`private` and `protected` mean the same here as they do elsewhere: `private` restricts access only to that very class, while `protected` restricts access to that class and all its derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

It makes a difference when you have a class model that uses inheritance. If your MyClass methods are clients of your private fields and methods it makes no difference.

That said, even if you don't anticipate your MyClass becoming a parent class in any sort of class hierarchy, it doesn't hurt to limit your field and method scope to the least visible scope that it requires. Encapsulate what you can with the least visible scope by default so that you don't have to refactor when subclasses start to access parent properties that they shouldn't be. The level of effort isn't any different from not doing so.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify no access modifiers on the `get` and `set` keywords, the property will be accessible according to the access modifier of the property itself. In your example, you would be able to get the value of Foo and set the value of Foo from anywhere in your program if you specify `get` instead of `private get`.

In order to write robust code, you should try to always choose the most restrictive access modifier possible. It is a good idea to use properties to expose the state of your object, but not to change the state of your object from outside. If you want to change the state of your object, use method calls instead.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the `get` and `set` functions in terms of accessor and mutator methods (except that you don't have to explicitly write the method bodies out:

```
private int foo;

public int get_Foo()
{
    return foo;
}

public /* or protected, or private */ void set_Foo(int value)
{
    foo = value;
}
```

After you see it like that, know that the `protected` and `private` modifiers work the same on a setter as they do on any other sort of member.